# Ramaa/Rema in the Shloka

Tags: shloka

In the below shloka, who is "ramaa"?

> umā uṣā ca vaidehī **ramā** gangeti panchakam
>
> prātareva smarennityaṃ saubhāgyaṃ vardhate sadā

I read a few online translations posting it as "consort of Vishnu--Rema"; if correct, who is Rema?

Comment: RamA refers to Lakshmi Devi. But in the link here (http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Pancha_Devi_Stuti) its Rema (not ramA) but still translated as consort of Vishnu.

Comment: @rickross thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [The S'rîmad Devî Bhâgawatam: Skandha 6: Chpater 17](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/db/bk06ch17.htm), Ramâ / Ramā / Ramaa is another name of Goddess Laksmî:

> 49-56. Vyâsa said :-- ... Once on a time Revanta, the son of the Sun, very beautiful and of boundless lustre, was going to Visnu in Vaikuntha, mounted on the beautiful Uchchais’rava, the jewel of the horses. When he was going on horseback with a desire to see the God Visnu, the Goddess Laksmî saw that child of the Sun. The Goddess Laksmî, born out of the churning of the ocean, on looking at the beautiful appearance of her brother Horse, also born out of the churning of the ocean, became very much astonished and steadily gazed on him. The Bhagavân Visnu, capable to show both favour and disfavour, saw the beautiful Revanta, of good figure, coming on horseback; and lovingly asked Laksmî :-- “O Beautiful One! Who is coming here on horseback, as it were, enchanting to the three worlds!” At that time, the Goddess Laksmî was accidentally looking intently on the horse; so she did not reply, though repeatedly asked by the Bhagavân.
>
> 57-68. The Laksmî Devî, always restless, was very much intent on the horse and was enchanted and She was looking steadily with great affection on the horse. Seeing this, the Bhagavân became angry and said :-- “O Beautiful-eyed One! What you are looking at so intently? Are you so much enchanted with the sight of the horse that you are not speaking to me a single word, though I am repeatedly asking you so often! **You lovingly dwell on all the objects; hence your name is Ramâ;** your mind is also very restless, therefore you would be known as Chanchalâ Devî (the restless Devî).

Here is the related [Sanskrit shloka](https://archive.org/details/DeviBhagavataWithHindiTranslationVolume1GitaPress/page/n815/mode/2up):

> [image]